# Android - Skewing a TextView

Tags: android, textview, skew

I want to skew / rotate text to look like the following

[image: Skewed text]

I image I would manipulate the canvas in `onDraw`, but I'm unsure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTextSkewX` method of the `Paint` class:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSkewX(-0.2f);
    canvas.drawText("Make It Supreme", 0, 0, paint);
}
```

Comment: Only the unformatted text from `super.onDraw(canvas)`